# PHP - Create a directory listing of specified folder

Tags: javascript, php

I've got small piece of code which I'm using to scan a certain directory on my server for all the files and folders inside. But there's a catch... It can only scan the specified folder, and no sub-directories. Let's say `share/` is the root directory for this scan, if there are files in any sub-directory like `share/folder/file.png` they won't be listed, where the entire purpose of my project is to create an HTML file explorer.

This is the code I'm using to receive the list of files from the server to later display it in the browser using JavaScript:

```
<?php
    $listFiles = array();

    if ($handle = opendir('./share')) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                $listFiles[] = $entry;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

    $FS_files = json_encode($listFiles);
?>
```

And then I "push" it rude to my actual JavaScript code like this:

```
let FS_files = <?php echo $FS_files ?>
```

The code I above basically generates an array of file names from scanned directory. What I wanna know is how can I get an ***entire*** JSON tree of files in this directory and all folders inside it, or possibly change my code so it works that way?

Comment: Very briefly, You can make a recursive function with your code that calls itself every time a directory is found (using is_dir() to check the filenames).

Comment: But if it finds a folder, and there were a couple of files left unchecked, would they get listed that way? I always had problems understanding that sort of things.

Comment: Yes, the remaining files/folders would be listed too. When you make a recursive call, after the recursively called function has been executed, the execution continues from the point after the recursive function call in the original function.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function scanFolder($dir) {
    $result = array();
    $cdir = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) {
                $result[$value] = scanFolder($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
            } else {
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$FS_files = json_encode(scanFolder("./share"));
?>
```

The function scans the folder and checks each entry with **is_dir**. If its true, this folder is scanned with the same function.

Comment: Right now I have no way to check if it works for me or not because I'm outside my house and my laptop is too old to run XAMPP or any other Apache server, so I'll check it a little later and accept the answer if it fixes my problem. But I think it's a preatty solid piece of code.